# How do I inject depencies into the thread

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have the following dilemma when I inject fiscalCalendarRepository, and when I go through the run it makes a query to the sql server database, but when I do it the result of extrusionL1DataList is NULL and it goes by the exception that I could do there

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class ExtrusionProcessThread extends Thread{
    
    private final String END_WITH_TAG = "_ACT";
    
    private ReadingProcessRepository readingProcessRepository;
    @Autowired
    private FiscalCalendarRepository fiscalCalendarRepository;
    private ManagerExtrusionL1Repository managerExtrusionL1Repository;
    private ManagerExtrusionL3Repository managerExtrusionL3Repository;
    private EmailService emailService;
    
    private ReadingProcessData data;
    private List<ReadingProcessResponse> extrusionL1DataList = new ArrayList<ReadingProcessResponse>();
    private List<ReadingProcessResponse> extrusionL3DataList = new ArrayList<ReadingProcessResponse>();
    
    private Long sleepTime;
    private boolean execution = true;
    private String notificationEmail;
    
    
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        
        while(execution) {
            System.out.println("Ejecucion Extrusion " + data.getLine() + " ---->" + Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            try {
                
                if (data.getLine().equals(LineEnum.LINE_1.getCodeLine())) {
                    extrusionL1DataList = fiscalCalendarRepository.findReadingVariables();
                } else {
                    extrusionL3DataList = readingProcessRepository.findReadingVariables(PlcVariablesMySqlEnum.TABLE_EXTRUSION_L3.getDescription());
                }
                
                //Guardar en mongo variables
                saveVariablesMongo();
                
                Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                validateExecution();
            }
            
        }
        
    }
```

here is the implementation of the query to the database

```
@Repository
public class FiscalCalendarRepositoryImpl implements FiscalCalendarRepository {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jdbcSqlServerService")
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    
    @Override
    public List<FiscalCalendar> getFiscalCalendar() {
        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
        query.append("SELECT * FROM SPC.dbo.fiscal_calendar ORDER BY berry_order");
        
        return jdbcTemplate.query(query.toString(), new FiscalCalendarMapper());
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getDaysBerryYear() {
        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
        query.append("SELECT SUM(days_number) FROM SPC.dbo.fiscal_calendar");
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query.toString(), null, Integer.class);
    }
    
    @Override
    public List<ReadingProcessResponse> findReadingVariables() {
            
            StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
            query.append("SELECT * FROM SPC.dbo.manager_l1");
            
            try {
                List<ReadingProcessResponse> dataProcessList = jdbcTemplate.query(query.toString(), new ReadingProcessResponseMapper());
                return dataProcessList;
            } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
                return new ArrayList<>();
            }
            
        }
```

suggestions to reach the solution

Comment: Hi King, I think the problem might lie in the code that starts the `ExtrusionProcessThread`. From my experience, it's not a good idea to deal with Thread-Objects directly in Spring. I would prefer the `@Async` annotation. See also https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/

Comment: you refer in the query method to the database, I could see it reflected in my code what you say